# What's the purpose of the type "block_settings" in schema.yml files?

Tags: 8

In the block_example module, from the Drupal 8 Examples for Developers, 
what purpose does the file [block_example.schema.yml](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/examples/tree/block_example/config/schema/block_example.schema.yml) serve?

I'm familiar with using schema.yml files to set configuration and access it like so:

```
$config = \Drupal::config('system.maintenance');
```

However, it appears that the "block_settings" type is different.

Answer (score 5):

That's basically config schema inheritance, like you have class inheritance in PHP.

*Any* type that you define can be used as by by someone else. And it is what you want to do when you extend the class (usually a plugin) for which it is defined.

block_settings itself is a type that extends from mapping and defines a few common keys, it is defined in core.data_types.schema.yml

```
block_settings:
  type: mapping
  label: 'Block settings'
  mapping:
    id:
      type: string
      label: 'ID'
    ...
```

(Multiple keys in there shouldn't exit and are for example block_content specific, but that's a bit complicated to fix now).

And if you'd provide a block plugin that would extend from example_configurable_text, then you can define it like this:

```
block.settings.my_block:
  type: block.settings.example_configurable_text
  mapping:
    another_thing:
      type: text
      label: 'Another thing'
```

And you automatically get everything it defines, and what it itself inherits from block_settings.

Comment: Thanks, @Berdir. I'm still wondering, though, how this inheritance plays out. In block_example.schema.yml, block.settings.example_configurable_text is of type block_settings, which has various keys like label and info. However, when run `\Drupal::config('block.block.titleoffirstblockexample_configurable_text')->get('label')` the result is null. If this block inherits from block_settings, I would expect to see a value or at least know how to set it. What am I missing?

Comment: block_settings define the block *settings*. try settings.label and so on. Also not all those keys exist all the time. the block itself is defined in block.schema.yml, and its settings is then block.settings.[%parent.plugin], so its gets its schema dynamically depending on the value of the type. See http://hojtsy.hu/blog/2014-dec-12/drupal-8-configuration-schema-cheat-sheet for more information